# Add redundancy to neural network

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

How do I make my neural network learn same pattern with minor modifications multiple times, that is one neural network learns minor modifications of the same pattern, and stores them in a list, and returns this list to another neural network?

if I do something like this,

```
class Model(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    self.lin = nn.Linear(3, 3)
  def forward(self, x):
    out = self.lin(x)
    return out, out
```

then it would return two outputs, but both of them would be same, I want redundancy, but not exactly same patterns, only minor modifications.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Is the plan to propagate separately over the two different outputs? In your case the output is exactly the same, so where is the modification?

Comment: what do you mean by redundancy ? do you need to return multiple outputs ? or output of the previous batch ?

Comment: i do not know how to return multiple similar outputs, the plan is to make it learn similar patterns, just like human brain is able to learn minor modifications in objects we see in daily life, after seeing one instance of that object.